# Can I overload -> in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to build a logic variable class that can do the following

```
x = LogicVar()
y = LogicVar()

property = x -> y
```

then this will give...

```
property(true, true) = true
property(true, false) = false
property(false, true) = true
property(false, false) = true
```

because I would be ideally be able to do something like

```
class LogicVar():
   ...

   def __dash_arrow_(self, other):
      def ifthen(x, y):
         return (not(x) or y)
      return ifthen
```

I know I can overload stuff like + or >=, but I don't know whether I can do -> even though I see it used in type hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. `->` is not an operator at all in Python. The only place a `->` token is permitted in the Python grammar is before the return type annotation in a function definition. Python operator overloading does not allow you to change the language syntax or create new operators.

Comment: The complete list of overridable operators is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), mostly in the section on [emulating numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types). If it is not on that page, it is not possible.

Comment: Thanks. Relatedly, I found this library which uses >> for implication instead of ->, which I guess is good enough for my use case also. https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html#